# I want to get Count the clicks on an item of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, count, nestedrecyclerview

I have a recyclerview,this recycler have 5 item[a,b,c,d,e].Suppose 10 user clicked this item[b].how can i get count = 10 and i want to store this count data in firebase database.(I am not using firebase recyclerview)
My another question is i have 5 list,i want to show 5 list item in one recyclerview randomly.
How can i get this.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to implement click listener on your recycler view.
   For each click, check which element has been clicked.
   You can save temporarily the count for each row somewhere and then save it to firebase.
2. Take the 5 list items you want. (randomly or by another way)
   Then create a recycler view and pass the 5 list items as a dataSource to your adapter.